# Object.assign() in add-on in Ember app causes problems in IE11

Tags: ember.js, babel-polyfill

I have an Ember app that uses several 3rd party add-ons.  One of these add-ons uses Object.assign() which causes problem in IE11, specifically the error

> Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'

I know why this is happening, but I'm relatively new to Ember, and am not sure of the best way to handle/fix this.  Based on my research, some options are:

Option 1: use **polyfills** (?)

I think there may be some additional libraries I can install, or options in Babel to set that will take care of this, but I have not been able to do so thus far.  It's unclear whether any of these options would affect code from add-ons anyway, or if they only apply to code in the primary app.

Option 2: **extend** the add-on component to avoid Object.assign().

Unfortunately, the problematic lines are in the component's init().  When my extended component calls this._super(), the code I'm trying to avoid is run anyway.  Is there a way to 'skip' the base component's init() and go straight to Ember's Component.init() (the add-on's _super()) ?

Option 3: ditch the 3rd party add-on, salvage what I can, and **make my own** component.
Irritating but do-able.  At this point, it probably would have been faster to do that from the start.

Option 4: **fix the add-on** to remove the problem code.  My hesitation here is two fold: 1, if this is something that I should somehow be managing within my app, it doesn't seem correct to make the add-on change (though there is definitely a 'best practices' argument to be made here).  The bigger concern is that this is a low activity add-on.  Even if I submit a PR with the change, I'm not sure how long it will take for a new release.
In the meantime, what would be the recommended practice?  Point my app to a local build and then remember to update it to an 'official' version if/when it is released?

I suspect that Option 1, polyfills and/or build settings, is the most correct course of action, but I'm at a loss for what, specifically, to do.

Additional info:
My app was developed with Ember 2.7, and I am in the process of updating it to Ember 3.1.  This issue exists in both builds.

Comment: option 4: submit a patch to the addon to use `Ember.assign` which uses native `Object.assign` when available and falls back to polyfill.

Comment: I agree with runspired. My first move would be to open an issue offering to fix it, and see if the maintainer responds. It’s the least work, if they are active!

Comment: I agree that 'fix the addon' would be the most straightforward.  My concerns were that 1, this was something that I should be handling myself somehow (Option 1) and 2, this is a low-activity addon.  I'm not sure how long it will take to get a new 'official' release even if I make a PR with the change.  I'll update the question. thanks

Comment: Good luck! A lot of maintainers can be reached via the Ember Community Slack if you don’t get a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [include polyfill](https://github.com/babel/ember-cli-babel#polyfill):

```
// ember-cli-build.js

let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  'ember-cli-babel': {
    includePolyfill: true
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.  And so simple!